# ViewPager with header view

Tags: android, android-listview, android-viewpager

I need to make layout that looks like this
[image]
There is header view (RelativeLayout), below is ViewPager Indicator and then ViewPager with pages (FragmentPagerAdapter) which contains ListView or ScrollView. Because header view can be big, whole layout should be scrollable.
My best try is to have ListView with two headers (Header view and ViewPager) - but this is very bad because of ListView inside another ListView and recycling problems.
What is the best approach to do that? Is there any method to add ViewPager header view as it can be done with ListView and addHeaderView() method?
Thank you for help!

Comment: Do you want the view pager to change page when you swipe left / right on the header, or do you want the header to move up / down when you scroll the list view? (or both?). Should the header move when you scroll / swipe your finger on the header (not the view pager / list view)?

Comment: Header is scrollable only vertically with ViewPager and its content. Header will not cause ViewPager to swipe pages. Try to imagine that as ordinary ListView with addHeaderView(Header) but instead ListView is ViewPager which contains ListView.

Comment: So your Header should be a ScrollView (vertical), or did I misunderstood ?

Comment: Header should be some basic layout (RelativeLayout, LinearLayout etc.) with no ScrollView. Some sort of ScrollView should be around whole layout which will contain Header, ViewPager and its pages (ListView etc.).

Comment: @Warlock I exactly facing that problem you introduced. Did you manage to find a solution?

Comment: @hasan After spending many hours on this problem I removed ViewPager and used ListView only. I'm using MergeAdapter (cwac-merge) with header with "fake" tabs and disabling/enabling items in MergeAdapter. I have no swipe function in there but it looks exactly the same as the picture above. But still I'm looking for the solution to the original problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can also achieve this effect by using the **Android-ParallaxHeaderViewPager** a good example of scrolling tab header by [kmshack Github page](https://github.com/kmshack)

The Sample code is give in this [Here Git Hub link](https://github.com/kmshack/Android-ParallaxHeaderViewPager)

[image]

The explanation for the solution is begin described in the github page

Hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

I know its not best solution to include ListView inside another ListView/ScrollView

Still for learning purpose you can check below link...

https://github.com/shabbirsphinx/funbook/tree/master/HeaderViewToViewPager

Answer (score 0):

Here's a neat library for the same:

https://github.com/noties/Scrollable

Answer (score -2):

I think this project [MagicHeaderViewPager](https://github.com/XavierSAndroid/MagicHeaderViewPager) easy to use and able to meet your need.

**How to implement simplest HeaderViewPager?**

1.Add dependencies in your build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.culiu.android:mhvp-core:2.1.2@aar'
}
```

2.Create a layout fragment_list.xml for your DemoListFragment.

3.Create DemoListFragment.java. You need to do something about your adapter and data.

4.Build your DemoPagerAdapter. Create a class DemoPagerAdapter, let it implement interface OutPagerAdapter.

5.Add MagicHeaderViewPager init into your DemoActivity.

Then, you can enjoy your MagicHeaderViewPager. For more details, see [Guide](https://github.com/XavierSAndroid/MagicHeaderViewPager/tree/master/doc) or demo code in Module Demo.

ViewPager and ListView/ScrollView have already been encapsulated in to controls.